# Image picker not working in flutter project

Tags: flutter

I am using the latest image picker to upload an image from the gallery. I get an error of error: The argument type 'XFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.
Please help if you are looking at it. I have used a lot of code snippets but nothing works.

I am using the latest image picker to upload an image from the gallery. I get an error of error: The argument type 'XFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.
Please help if you are looking at it. I have used a lot of code snippets but nothing works.

```
    import 'dart:io';
import 'package:driver_pilot/date_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:driver_pilot/components/components.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  late XFile _image;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  Future getImage() async {
    XFile? pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = pickedFile!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Sign Up',
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Stack(children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 48),
                      height: 60,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 40.0,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  radius: 14.0,
                                  // child: Icon(
                                  //   Icons.camera_alt,
                                  //   size: 15.0,
                                  //   color: Color(0xFF404040),
                                  // ),
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    iconSize: 15.0,
                                    onPressed: getImage,
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              radius: 68.0,
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://comicvine.gamespot.com/a/uploads/scale_medium/12/124259/7538232-three-jokers-1-cvr-fnl-1583776056592.jpg'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ]),
                  // SizedBox(
                  //   height: 20.0,
                  // ),
                  BuildFirstName(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  BuildLastName(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  BuildSignUpPhone(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  BirthDate(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: _image == null
                        ? Text('No image selected')
                        : Image.file(_image),
                  ),
                  LabelForCamUpload(
                    label: 'Civil Id',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  CamUploadWidget(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),
                  LabelForCamUpload(
                    label: 'Driving Licence',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  CamUploadWidget(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),
                  LabelForCamUpload(
                    label: 'Vehicle Registration',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  CamUploadWidget(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 30.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: 'By signing up, you\'re agreeing to our ',
                              style: kTermsAndCondTextStyle),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: 'Terms of Service and Privacy Policy.',
                            style: kTermsAndCondTextStyle.copyWith(
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            ),
                            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                              ..onTap = () async {
                                final url =
                                    'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://www.urwagon.com/wagon_backendV2/public/policy_terms/WagonPrivacyPolicy.pdf';
                                if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                                  await launch(
                                    url,
                                    forceSafariVC: false,
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'SIGN UP',
                      style: kButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: kWagonColour,
                      fixedSize: Size(325.0, 40.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem or error?

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question. Maybe add [repro] instead of just your code

Answer (score 5):

The reason being is that XFile is a different parameter than File. So you should do like this:

```
File _image;
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
Future getImage() async {
  var pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  setState(() {
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
late File _image;

setState(() {
   File_image = pickedFile!.toFile();
});
```

}

Try converting xfile into file.
Please refer this link https://pub.dev/packages/xfile